# iOS 9 UIInputViewController dismissKeyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uiinputviewcontroller

I have a custom `UIInputViewController`, let's call it `MyInputViewController`. I set the a text field's input view to the view of a singleton instance of my input controller. Inserting, deleting and moving the cursor works fine however when I call `self.dismissKeyboard()` in the input view controller (method is called, print() writes to the console), it doesn't do anything.

What could be wrong? It got it to work a few days ago however I couldn't remember what might be the error.

```
class MyInputController: UIInputViewController {

// SINGLETON:
static let keyboard: MyInputController = MyInputController()

class func setSharedKeyboardForTextField(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.inputAccessoryView = nil
    textField.inputView = keyboard.view
}

// MARK: initializers
private init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false=
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //set up buttons
}

// MARK: helper functions
func inputText() -> String {
    return (self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput ?? "") + (self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput ?? "")
}

// MARK: animations
private func grow(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    sender.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(sender)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) { () -> Void in
        sender.transform = scaleTransform
    }
}

private func shrink(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    sender.superview?.sendSubviewToBack(sender)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1) { () -> Void in
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
}

// MARK: actions
func keyTouched(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    grow(sender)
}

func keyExit(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    shrink(sender)
}

func resign(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // called but doesn't work
    dismissKeyboard()
    shrink(sender)
}

func keyPressed(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(sender.insertion)
    shrink(sender)
}

func remove(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
    shrink(sender)
}

func clear(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    while self.textDocumentProxy.hasText() {
        self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
    }
    shrink(sender)
}

func moveLeft(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(-1)
    shrink(sender)
}

func moveRight(sender: MathematicalKeyboardKey) {
    // works
    self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(1)
    shrink(sender)
}
```

}

Comment: can you put your complete code?

Comment: 8 years later I have the same problem

Answer (score -2):

You can use ;

```
 resignFirstResponder()
```

method instead of

```
 dismissKeyboard()
```

method.

```
@IBAction func hideKeyboard(sender: UIButton) {

    resignFirstResponder()

}
```